# A riddle in verbs

Tags: riddle

> Break, leave, begin.
>   Rove, tear, grow.
>   Stop, build, sleep.
>   Break, leave, unfold.
>   Glide, lay, end.

Comment: This is not related, but do you know what the general word is for puzzles which are told in rhyme which describe a mysterious object ?

Comment: @user230452 I'm afraid I don't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Answer:**

> **Butterfly Life Cycle / Butterfly Metamorphosis**

Break, leave, begin.

> Larva is born from egg.

Rove, tear, grow.

> Caterpillar wanders around to eat and grow.

Stop, build, sleep.

> Eventually, stops and starts converting to cocoon(chrysalis), sleeps.

Break, leave, unfold.

> Then, breaks open the cocoon, leaves the cocoon(chrysalis), and unfolds its wings.

Glide, lay, end.

> Flies to lay eggs for new generation and then dies.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's referring to

> Story of a Tree

Here's How

Break, leave, begin.

> Leaves/seeds break from the trees and here it's journey begins

Rove, tear, grow.

> it travels aimlessly with the wind, gets deccayed and rises up again as a seedling/ plant/tree

Stop, build, sleep.

> stops growing after a time, and also sleeps in the night-> by closing it's leaves like **Touch me not plant**

Break, leave, unfold.

> when the dawn breaks, leaves unfold

Glide, lay, end.

> after some/many years all the leaves begin to fall  from the tree and the tree dies. And this is how it's journey ends

I might not have given exactly correct explanation  in the explanation, and would like your opinions in the comment

Comment: Nice answer, with nice explanations! Not the one I am looking for though; the explanation to "Stop, build, sleep" doesn't fit as well as it could.